# Javascript Higher Order Function:

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am learning HOF at the moment:

```js
weaponsWithNoises = [
  { name: "Phaser", noise: "bssszzsssss", universe: "Star Trek" },
  { name: "Blaster", noise: "Pew Pew", universe: "Star Wars" },
  { name: "Sonic Screwdriver", noise: "Pew Pew", universe: "Dr. Who" },
  { name: "Lightsaber", noise: "Pew Pew", universe: "Star Wars" },
  { name: "Noisy Cricket", noise: "Pew Pew", universe: "Men in Black" },
];


function weaponsFromUniverse(universe) {
  const useableWeapons = weaponsWithNoises.filter(
    (w) => w.universe == universe
  );
  const useWeapon = (weaponName) => {
    const weapon = useableWeapons.find((w) => weaponName == w.name);
    if (weapon) {
      console.log(`used ${weapon.name}: ${weapon.noise}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`${weaponName} is not a part of the ${universe} universe`);
    }
  };

  return useWeapon;
}

// USAGE
const useStarWarsWeapon = weaponsFromUniverse("Star Wars");

useStarWarsWeapon("Blaster"); // console logs 'used Blaster: Pew Pew'
useStarWarsWeapon("Noisy Cricket"); // console logs 'Noisy Cricket is not a part of the Star Wars universe'
```

In this example, I am really confused, for the usage section:

```
const useStarWarsWeapon = weaponsFromUniverse("Star Wars");
```

At this line, "Star Wars" is passed to `weaponsFromUniverse`, then this function is assigned to `useStarWarsWeapon`, then "Blaster" is passed to `useStarWarsWeapon`:

`useStarWarsWeapon("Blaster");`

Why "Blaster" can be naturally passed to `useWeapon` in the `weaponsFromUniverse`?

Comment: "*Why "Blaster" can be naturally passed to useWeapon in the weaponsFromUniverse?*" you could call it as `weaponsFromUniverse("Star Wars")("Blaster")` but you cannot otherwise *directly* pass the argument. You need the result of `weaponsFromUniverse("Star Wars")` first.

Comment: `weaponsFromUniverse` returns a function. This can then be used by the const `useStarWarsWeapon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

weaponsFromUniverse returns useWeapon which is a function that receives one parameter called weaponName.

When doing:

```
 const useStarWarsWeapon = weaponsFromUniverse("Star Wars");
```

Then useStarWarsWeapon is a function that receives one parameter called weaponName.

Therefore, you can call that function with whatever parameter you want. For example, with Blaster by doing this:

```
useStarWarsWeapon("Blaster");
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing out that useWeapon is the returned function, it clear to me now.